# I want to make a file edit and a program start stop from browser on a Ubuntu VPS - Is it possible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, browser

I have this file called names.txt and its location is in home folder of Ubuntu /home/abc/names.txt, I want to be able to edit it using browser by going to http://IP and edit the names.txt file from browser and it saves instead of ssh and doing NANO or ftp and edit, I want other users to go to http://IP and edit the file and save.

Secondly, I also want to be able to run a shell script from browser say ./file.sh I want to be able to go to http://IP and click on run and it will run the file or execute a command say

cd /home/abc/
screen
./file

Is it possible over apache and web based?

Comment: You could try etherpad.org for collaborative editing you can host yourself

Comment: `I also want to be able to run a shell script from browser say ./file.sh I want to be able to go to http://IP and click on run and it will run the file or execute a command` What if someone decides to format your drive(s)?

Comment: Browsers usually execute in a sandbox that doesn't allow running programs from inside the browser.

Comment: So the thing is, I have this file that needs to add IP to whitelist to enter a server, so I want my clients to go the the IP via web browser and add their desired IP *who has dynamic IP* and save it and once clicked on save the file needs to restart for the IP to work, say file.sh and it will only then whitelist the IP. Is it possible with 777 chmod of the file to be able to edit the .config file and save as I do not want to give FTP or remote access to root for the server to my clients

Comment: @Gantendo I want to make a php script with button say if clicked on button X it will execute the command on the system cd /home/abc/ screen ./file